# Retrofit2 POST отправка на сервер PHP

Tags: php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

```
Retrofit rt;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();
    rt=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://...").addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create()).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();


    Foo foo=rt.create(Foo.class);

    //Map<String,String> mapp=new HashMap<>();
    //mapp.put("author","author");
    Call<String> msg=foo.postJson("msg");

    msg.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

            Log.v("STERLITAMAK", response.body().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.v("STERLITAMAK", t.toString());

        }
    });
```

Код интерфейса

```
public interface Foo {

    @GET("Singleton")
    Call<String> getJson(@Query("weneed") String author);

    @POST("Singleton")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<String> postJson(@Field("weneed") String author);

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Singleton")
    Call<String> postJson1(@FieldMap Map<String,String> data);
}
```

Код PHP на сервере

```
echo $_POST["weneed"];
```

На сервер данные в виде POST не приходят. Я уже не представляю в чем может быть ошибка, почти уверен что не на сервере ошибка, так как метод в интерфейсе getJson работает как надо.

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($_POST)`. А лучше настройте логирование в Retrofit

Comment: @rjhdby array(0) {
    } var_dump выдал это. Как настроить логирование не подскажете?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Comment: Тем не менее, есть еще какие то варианты? @rjhdby

Comment: Гадать можно очень долго. Гораздо проще один раз посмотреть запрос и ответ на него

Comment: @rjhdby https://pastebin.com/51pkVyB6 Если я правильно понял, то тут хранятся результаты логирования.

Comment: Данные на сервер отправляются корректно. Проблема на сервере, давайте код PHP скрипта смотреть.

Comment: @SergeMarkov 

echo $_POST['weneed'];
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$responce это массив который получен из базы. Он присылается в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр у аннотации POST - URL куда идет отправка. Наиболее вероятная причина - на сервере установлен параметр http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.enable-post-data-reading - скорее всего он выставлен в  off.

Comment: Так и есть. Все запросы принимает один скрипт. Там построена factory, поэтому сначала принимается то, что приходит на сервер, и только потом приходит ответ от сервера. А что не так?

Comment: @SergeMarkov Это параметр был закомментирован и у него был установлен параметр off. Я его раскомментировал и установил в on. Но так как я до этого использовал post в Volley, я думаю проблема не в этом.

Comment: Давайте исключим Android и тестами через Postman или другой REST тул (например в PHPStorm/IDEA) добиться корректного ответа с сервера.

Comment: @SergeMarkov Протестировал с помощью Postman. На сервер не приходит запрос POST

Comment: Значит проблема со скриптом или конфигурацией PHP. Скиньте конфиги apache, .htaccess и php.ini

Comment: @SergeMarkov https://pastebin.com/qT37gY0K - Apache
https://pastebin.com/L5FUHbBT - .htaccess
https://pastebin.com/mN05BvT3 - php.ini. Там еще 2 файла php development и php-production

Comment: @SergeMarkov Еще я обнаружил, что если отправлять через форму html, то запрос POST работает.

Comment: давайте сравнивать что отправляется в консоле Chrome и то что отправляете в Postman.

Comment: На сервере есть файл, в котором хранится следующий код: echo  'DEBUG'.$_POST['say'];

В Postman отправляется(в Body) Параметр say со значением hey. Также там установлен Header Content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
В Postman ответ приходит в виде DEBUG. Если я использую форму, с параметром, и после этого отправляю submit, то $_POST работает так как надо. Какие именно данные вам нужны из консоли? Которые выводятся при работе с формой?

Comment: Давайте сравним полный POST от формы и postman, возможно сможем понять какого хидера не хватает.

Comment: https://imgur.com/39Qp2mS Это результат в консоли Chrome когда я выбрал меню Header. И ответ Postman соответственно https://imgur.com/QhepnpE. Если я все правильно понял